# How to connect DB on others server via intranet in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am new in .net. I know the basic to connect db on my localhost. But I need to connect to others db in intranet. He provided me with the connection strings. I put the provided connection string in config file. So what else should I do before any data can shown/ or how I know it is working?

Comment: show the connection string

Comment: <add name="TSPConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source= LI-GTSPD01.hilti.com\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TSP_LT;uid=TSP;pwd=hilti1234"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the SQL Server to allow remote connection

see the link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

Also the fire wall has to be allow remote acces for SQL server.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx